# Slow MySQL in a laptop(localhost), faster in a production machine(desktop)

Tags: mysql

What are the reasons when I am connecting to the MySQL server in my laptop(development machine) using MySQL Administrator it is too slow, but when I am connecting to the MySQL server in the prouction machine it is faster. Does setting on the logs have a noticeable performance drop? I have no problems before with slow connections with my laptop.

Answer (score 7):

- A lot of companies put extra AV/firewall protection on laptops that they don't on desktops.  That may be slowing you down.
- Hard drive encryption is often found on corporate laptops which slows things down
- Your laptop may have less memory than your desktop
- Your laptop may have slower memory than your desktop
- Your laptop may have a slower CPU than your desktop
- Your laptop probably has less hard drive space than your desktop
- Your laptop probably has a slower hard drive than your laptop
- Your laptop's hard drive may be badly fragmented
- You may have more programs running on your laptop than your desktop

Comment: The only thing you missed: Many laptop HD's run at abysmal speeds like 4200rpm or 5600rpm.  This will devastate DB performance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firefox?  You may want to try editing the `network.dns.disableIPv6` setting.

Type `about:config` in the address bar and filter for `network.dns.disableIPv6` and double-click to set to true.